# Minimal graph such that the greedy pathing algorithm always terminates

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Saw this question languishing on Reddit and decided it could stand a signal boost.  Since I'm not familiar with the area, it might be quite elementary, but it's at least interesting from a layman's perspective.

Let $(X, d)$ be a finite metric space [1].  Consider a connected graph $G = (X, E)$.  Define the *greedy pathing algorithm*:

> **Input:** $x_1, x_2 \in X$.
>
> Set $y = x_1$.
>
> While $y \neq x_2$:
>
> $\hspace{0.5in}$ Output $y$.
>
> $\hspace{0.5in}$ Find the point $z$ among those adjacent to $y$ such that $d(z, x_2)$ is minimal.
>
> $\hspace{0.5in}$ Set $y = z$.
>
> Output $x_2$

In other words, attempt to move from $x_1$ to $x_2$ by always moving towards the accessible point closest to $x_2$.  Clearly this terminates for some graphs and not others -- it's easy to see how it can get stuck in a local minimum and bounce back and forth between two edges.

**Problem**: Given a space $(X, d)$, find the smallest graph $G$ such that the greedy pathing algorithm terminates for every pair $x_1, x_2 \in X$.

**Question**: Obviously there's a brute-force algorithm that solves the problem.  Is there a more efficient algorithm?  Of course there are related questions here: can the property that the greedy pathing algorithm always terminates be rephrased in a better way?

Note: In the original question, we have also that $(X, d)$ embeds into a flat torus.  I'm not sure whether that helps.

Original here: http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1r6zv1/i_have_a_graph_theory_problem_i_think_its_graph/

[1] To avoid excess drama, let's assume that no two pairs of points are the same distance apart, i.e. that $d(x_1, x_2) \neq d(x_3, x_4)$ for $x_1 \neq x_2$, $x_3 \neq x_4$, and $\{x_1, x_2\} \neq \{x_3, x_4\}$.

Comment: "Obviously there's a brute-force algorithm that solves the problem." What exactly is "the problem" here? You just posed a problem but that does not seem to be the one you are referring here.

Comment: It is the one I'm referring to.  By "the problem" I mean what I've written next to "Problem:."  I want an algorithm that finds the minimal graph on these points such that the property "the greedy pathing algorithm always terminates" holds.